# Computer can not play sounds when bluetooth speaker connected

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

This is not a case of me not being able to *hear* the sounds, but rather my computer seems incapable of playing them in the first place. For example, Youtube videos cannot play, and the Videos app will not even start an MP3. If I turn off the bluetooth speaker, everything works fine.

This is a Photive speaker and I have configured it via Ubuntu "Sounds" app as well as "Pulse Audio Control" to use the High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) option. I've also tried using the "Bluetooth Manager" app (blueman) as well as restarting the devices, and some other questions on AskUbuntu / StackExchange. I would gratefully appreciate any help.

Comment: Try the command `sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`.

Comment: @Tim it says Failure: Module initialization failed

Comment: In bluetooth manager it says Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink as well

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It's nearly 1am for me so I'm not going to look into it for the next 17 hours (6pm GMT) or so, but I'll do some digging and try and work out the issue. BTW that command worked for me (on 16.04) until about a month ago - no idea why it broke.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I tried following the instructions there. Restarted the bluetooth service. It's showing up fine in pavucontrol however if I play a mp3 in videos then it just stays at 0:00. If i switch to laptop speakers then it starts to play.

Comment: Don't restart the bluetooth service after running the python script.  I never tried playing mp3's but I know youtube videos wouldn't play until I used the script

Comment: @Jeremy31 it says `Cannot find 'bluez_card.FC_58_FA_AD_99_93' using 'pactl list cards short'`

Comment: Does `pactl list short | grep blue` show module-bluetooth-discover in the results?